# fullCalendar Orientation - Views

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Does anyone have an idea how to manipulate with the orientation days and hours. For example I want my calendar looks like:[full calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8V1e.png)

Comment: Hi and thanks you for your interest, i try to find out how to configure calendar to looks that have on left side days in week, see my picture in question.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an implementation of the requested view, after a [very long analysis and development](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=150) there is a scheduler: http://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/